# IIS 8.5 UrlRewrite Outbound Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5, outbound

been scratching my head on this outbound rule. note I am not an expert in regular expressions and that might be the problem.

My rule is a simple static rewrite. i want to create an outbound response rule for this url:
    /test/test.aspx?g=sss&f=123   to /test/my-sample.aspx

Here is my rule so far but nothing is happening, any help would be appreciated.

```
<outboundRules>
<rule name="Test">
<match filterByTags="A, Area, Base" pattern="^(.*)/test/test.aspx?g=sss&amp;f=123" />                    
<action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/test/my-sample.aspx" />
</rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Your regex should work. Do you have any other outbound rules set which could prevent this rule from executing? Have you tested your pattern against real values in your href attributes to see what's being matched? When you try to load the page, do you see the unchanged content or do you get 500.xx error response?

Comment: @nanestev: I got a little closer, It appears that the query-string is not being evaluated, so I added a pre-condition which is getting me closer to having this work. Can someone confirm that query-string will not be evaluated as part of the match pattern like in my sample code and that I need to use a pre-condition for any query string evaluation?

Comment: Actually, with outbound rules the whole attribute value is being evaluated as a string. What probably happens is that your regex expression is misleading having the question mark which is part of the regex syntax. Escape it with \?  and try again.